# change windows local user password with administrator

Tags: c#, change-password, directoryentry

First, here's my code

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1},user", computerIP, "Administrator"), "Administrator", "adminPW", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

foreach (DirectoryEntry childEntry in directoryEntry.Parent.Children)
{
    if (childEntry.SchemaClassName == "User" && childEntry.Name == "OtherUser")
    {
       childEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "newPassword" });
       childEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

The situation is:

1. "OtherUser" is an account can't change its own password.
2. I use administrator login and find target account to set password but got access denied error.

So, how could I change this "OtherUser"'s password which can't change by itself?

Comment: Do you have support of the folks running the domain? It seems like OtherUser doesn't have permission to set the original user's password.

Comment: Administrator and OtherUser are on the same machine, doesn't join AD server

Comment: And OtherUser  has been set can't change password,so I need administrator to change its password.